# How to use the intent inform in Rasa?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to create a chatbot for banking. Flow is,

```
User: hi 
Bot: Welcome to ABC bank services. Let me know your name?
User: Kabeer 
Bot: Hi kabeer, how can i help you?
 Buttons:
 1: Loan (/inform{“service_type”:“Loan”})
 2: Deposit (/inform{“service_type”:“Deposit”})
 3: Account Types (/inform{“service_type”:“Account Types”})
 4: Customer Support No (/inform{“service_type”:“Customer Support No”})
 5: Service Request (/inform{“service_type”:“Service Request”})
 6: Careers (/inform{“service_type”:“Careers”})
Type out your own message…
User: 1: Loan (/inform{“service_type”:“Loan”})
Bot:Please select the required Loan type from the list
  Buttons:
1: Personal Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Personal Loan”})
2: Home Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Home Loan”})
3: Two-wheeler Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Two-wheeler Loan”})
4: Car Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Car Loan”})
5: Gold Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Gold Loan”})
Type out your own message…
User:Car Loan (/inform{“loan_type”:“Car Loan”})
 Bot: Uttering home loan here.
```

Issue is the bot always utter home loan only. The bot is not recognise the stories for other loans using entity. How can i make this work? I used inform intent because of i thought it will cause [similar intnent](https://blog.rasa.com/rasa-nlu-in-depth-part-1-intent-classification/) problem

Here is my code.

```
      ## say goodbye
  * goodbye
    - utter_goodbye

  ## bot challenge
  * bot_challenge
    - utter_iamabot

  ## happy_path_personal_loan_01
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - utter_personal_loan
  * goodbye
      - utter_goodbye
  ## happy_path_home_loan_01
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Home Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Home Loan"}
      - utter_home_loan
  * goodbye
      - utter_goodbye

  ## happy_path_car_loan_01
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kabeer"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Car Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Car Loan"}
      - utter_car_loan

  ## interactive_story_1
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Home Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Home Loan"}
      - utter_home_loan

  ## interactive_story_2
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kumar"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kumar"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - utter_personal_loan
      - action_restart

  ## interactive_story_3
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Car Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Car Loan"}
      - utter_car_loan
      - action_restart

  ## interactive_story_4
  * greet
      - utter_greet
  * PERSON{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - slot{"PERSON": "kiran"}
      - utter_ask_help
  * inform{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - slot{"service_type": "Loan"}
      - utter_ask_loan_type
  * inform{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - slot{"loan_type": "Personal Loan"}
      - utter_personal_loan
      - action_restart
```

**domain.yml**

```
        actions:
    - utter_ask_help
    - utter_ask_loan_type
    - utter_car_loan
    - utter_cheer_up
    - utter_did_that_help
    - utter_goodbye
    - utter_greet
    - utter_happy
    - utter_home_loan
    - utter_iamabot
    - utter_personal_loan
    entities:
    - PERSON
    - loan_type
    - service_type
    intents:
    - greet
    - inform
    - PERSON
    - goodbye
    - affirm
    - deny
    - bot_challenge
    slots:
      PERSON:
        type: text
      loan_type:
        type: text
      service_type:
        type: text
    templates:
      utter_ask_help:
      - buttons:
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Loan"}
          title: Loan
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Deposit"}
          title: Deposit
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Account Types"}
          title: Account Types
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Customer Support No"}
          title: Customer Support No
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Service Request"}
          title: Service Request
        - payload: /inform{"service_type":"Careers"}
          title: Careers
        text: Hi {PERSON}, how can i help you?
      utter_ask_loan_type:
      - buttons:
        - payload: /inform{"loan_type":"Personal Loan"}
          title: Personal Loan
        - payload: /inform{"loan_type":"Home Loan"}
          title: Home Loan
        - payload: /inform{"loan_type":"Two-wheeler Loan"}
          title: Two-wheeler Loan
        - payload: /inform{"loan_type":"Car Loan"}
          title: Car Loan
        - payload: /inform{"loan_type":"Gold Loan"}
          title: Gold Loan
        text: Please select the required Loan type from the list
      utter_car_loan:
      - text: LTV up to 100% on select models, faster processing of loans, easy documentation.
      utter_cheer_up:
      - image: https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg
        text: 'Here is something to cheer you up:'
      utter_did_that_help:
      - text: Did that help you?
      utter_goodbye:
      - text: Bye
      utter_greet:
      - text: Welcome to Voxtron bank services. Let me know your name?
      utter_happy:
      - text: Great, carry on!
      utter_home_loan:
      - text: Loans from 25,000 to 50 lakhs. Attractive interest rates, zero prepayment
          charges, affordable EMIs.
      utter_iamabot:
      - text: I am a bot, powered by Rasa.
      utter_personal_loan:
      - text: Loans up to 20 lakhs at attractive interest, no collateral & flexible repayment.
          Documents Required to apply, KYC and Income Documents are mandatory for applying
          a Personal Loan. Additional documents may be requested on a case to case basis.
```

**nlu.md**

```
  ## intent:inform
  - How can i apply for a [loan](service_type)
  - i want to get a [car loan](loan_type)
  - i want to apply for [personal loan](loan_type)
  - please let me know how can i apply for a [loan](service_type)
  - [gold loan](loan_type) details please
  - how to get a [home loan](loan_type)
  - I would like to know about the [gold loan](loan_type)
  - what are the conditions to get a [home loan](loan_type)
  - please send me the details about [vehicle loans](loan_type)
  - I would like to take a [housing loan](loan_type)
  - How am I supposed to apply for a [two wheeler loans](loan_type)
  - [car loan](loan_type)
  - [personal loan](loan_type)
  - [gold loan](loan_type)
  - [home loan](loan_type)
  - [vehicle loan](loan_type)
  - [housing loan](loan_type)
  - [loan](service_type)
  - [loans](service_type)
```

Answer (score 3):

slots of type `text` are featurized in a way that it only affects the story flow if they are set or not ([docs for it here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/#text-slot))
I think in your case you rather want to use a `categorical` slot. In this case the stories will go down different paths depending on the slot value ([docs for it here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/#categorical-slot))